# Best practices for probing for symbol visibility extensions in autoconf

Tags: c, shared-libraries, portability, autoconf, symbols

I'd like to add symbol hiding for internal symbols to an existing library with an autoconf-based build system. What's the best way to probe for the local compiler's equivalent for `-fvisibility=hidden` and `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard macro for this, but here is something which you should be able to extend to support other compilers as needed, e.g. `__hidden` for Sun compilers:

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([for __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))],
    ac_cv_hidden_visibility_attribute, [
    echo 'int __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) foo (void) { return 1; }' > conftest.c
    ac_cv_hidden_visibility_attribute=no
    if AC_TRY_COMMAND(${CC-cc} -Werror -S conftest.c -o conftest.s 1>&AS_MESSAGE_LOG_FD);
    then
        if grep '\.hidden.*foo' conftest.s >/dev/null;
        then
            ac_cv_hidden_visibility_attribute=yes
        fi
    fi
    rm -f conftest.*
    ])
if test $ac_cv_hidden_visibility_attribute = yes;
then
    AC_DEFINE(HAVE_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE, 1,
          [Define if __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) is supported.])
fi
```

The resulting `config.h`:

```
/* Define if __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) is supported. */
#define HAVE_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For `-fvisibility=hidden` I use this autoconf-archive macro:

```
AX_COMPILER_FLAGS([AM_CFLAGS],[AM_LDFLAGS],[$ax_is_release],[-fvisibility=hidden])
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compiler_flags.html,
but https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_append_compile_flags.html or http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_gcc_func_attribute.html can also be used. AX_COMPILER_FLAGS does most of what you'll need regarding warnings flags also. For the `$ax_is_release` see `AX_IS_RELEASE` also there.

For the attribute I use this check:

```
AC_CACHE_CHECK([for __attribute__((visibility("default")))],
  ac_cv_attribute_visibility_default, [
  ac_cv_attribute_visibility_default=no
  AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(
    [[ int __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) foo (void) { return 1; } ]], [])],
    [ac_cv_attribute_visibility_default=yes])
  ])
if test x$ac_cv_attribute_visibility_default = xyes;
then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_DEFAULT, 1,
    [Define if __attribute__((visibility("default"))) is supported.])
fi
```

Comment: Won't this define `HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_DEFAULT` on Cygwin and MinGW?

Comment: Yugr: you are right, good catch. There the declspec needs to be used. But I do that in my header before the HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY_DEFAULT check

Comment: IIRC, the visibility attribute was added in GCC 4.0 and older versions only produce a warning when encountering an unsupported attribute. So you should compile with `-Werror`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `<sys/cdefs.h>` with macro `__hiden`

Comment: There's no `__hidden` there at least on Ubuntu 16.04. And I couldn't locate it in Glibc source code either.